# ASM - How can I convert Java class name from Java bytecode name?

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I'm using ASM (a bytecode modification library) and it provides access to type names in the bytecode naming format, for example a String field is reported to have the description: Ljava/lang/String

I need to invoke Class.forName for some classes, but I need the source code form of the type names for that, e.g. java.lang.String.

Is there a way of converting from internal name to Java source format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know any API method, but the conversion is quite simple. You cand find details in [JVM spec here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#7028).
Primitive types are represented by one character:

B = byte
C = char
D = double
F = float
I = int
J = long
S = short
Z = boolean

Class and interface types are represented by the fully qualified name, with an
'L' prefix and a ';' suffix. The dots '.' in the fully qualified class name are
replaced by '/' (for inner classes, the '.' separating the outer class name from the inner class name is replaced by a '$'). So the internal name of the String class would be "Ljava/lang/String;" and the internal name of the inner class "java.awt.geom.Arc2D.Float" would be "Ljava/awt/geom/Arc2D$Float;".

Array names begin with an opening bracket '[' followed by the component type name (primitive or reference). An "int[]" thus becomes "[I" and a "javax.swing.JFrame[][]" becomes "[[Ljavax.swing.JFrame;".

Comment: With the caveat that you cannot actually instantiate an inner class dynamically using its FQN. You need to use the same name as would be returned by Class.getName() instead - in this case java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Float.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for some api, but I'll do it manually in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`org.objectweb.asm.Type.getInternalName(java.lang.Class)`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getInternalName%28java.lang.Class%29).

Comment: This is wrong in 2 ways.  1)  The OP wants to convert from the internal form to the source code form.  This method goes the other way.  2)  The OP wants to convert a String so that he can pass it as an argument to `Class.forName()`.  Obviously, he doesn't have the `Class` object at this point.

Comment: A correct way would be `Type.getObject(className).getClassName()`.

Comment: FlightOfStairs, why don't you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
org.objectweb.asm.Type.getType(typeDescriptor).getClassName()
```

Example: for `Ljava/lang/Deprecated;` returns `java.lang.Deprecated`.
Found this thanks to hint from @FlightOfStairs who pointed at right class.